# Can you compile complicated WinForms apps on the .NET Core 3.0 with AOT / CoreRT?

Tags: c#, aot, corert

I'm attempting to make a Windows forms application and compile it with CoreRT. When the app is simple, compilation works correctly; everything is compiled and the managed code is converted into natiive. However, if I do more than add a couple of buttons to the form, e.g. "Changing the icon", the application won't run when compiled? If anyone knows why, please let me know! Thanks.

The only code written was "MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "Current Date Time Native", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);" The problem I'm having is that the application compiles and runs only when basic controls are used. As soon as I add an icon to the application when I compile and try to run it, nothing happens. It doesn't even start.

The only thing I'm able to do in order to get the application to compile and run is add simple controls such as buttons and labels from the .NET toolbox. Adding something such as an Icon, or even changing the name results in the application compiling but when I try to run it, it doesn't start.

Comment: Welcome. Thank you for taking the time to share your question. There is something missing. What is your goal & difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, dev env, data types & expected result, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of screens, & user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: What's happen? What is the problem? Does it compile? What the error or the exception? Is it a UI rendering problem? Is there some code wrutten (add it, please), or only adding controls causes the problem? Are these controls from Microsoft .NET or provided by a third party?

Comment: The only code written was "MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "Current Date Time Native", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);" The problem I'm having is that the application compiles and runs only when basic controls are used. As soon as I add an icon to the application when I compile and try to run it, nothing happens. It doesn't even start

Comment: Either there is a problem with the embedded title bar icon or it is not supported by CoreRT ... I do not know about WinRT and I cannot verify. How do you add it? By setting it in the project settings and resource file, adding it in the form using the visual property editor, or loading it dynamically by code?

Comment: I have added via the visual designer, defined it in the project settings and yet upon compiling, the application won't run.

Comment: Try one thing at a time and see what's happen. Also try another icon file. Also Check the file format (perhaps an esoterical icon). Also try an image png/jpeg/bmp instead of a .ico. Also, keep in mind that the form's title bar icon uses 16x16 (no matters the color's depth, as I know, it is just ugly in 8bits).

Comment: Thank you - I will try that now.

Comment: To load at runtime in the form load event or the constructor: `Icon = new Icon(filePath);`.

Comment: I did every step one at a time and found two issues. When I change the icon of the form in the visual designer and compile, the application runs but the icon is still the default icon. I also found that when I define the icon in properties and compile, the application won't even start.

Comment: By code, no project icon nor design time: put a breakpoint on the create icon. What's happen before and after the line (use message boxes instead of breakpoint in no debugger)? had you try with a different image/icon?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.  Long answer, check https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues/7995 for a list of partially working controls, most are missing as COM support is missing from CoreRT at present.

Comment: As CoreRt has been promoted to NativeAot (https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/issues/1100) the updated situation is much better and nearly all controls are working.